# Powershell - Strange issue with script when searching for Ethernet Adapter

Tags: powershell, ethernet

I'm not even sure if this is a programming issue or something strange in Windows

I am creating a script in PowerShell 4.0 to automate the setting up of a Windows 6in4 tunnel.

The script is working successfully on my machine however when someone else using the same version tries it, the script fails for them.

The sticking point appears to be here

```
# First Locate Which device is the Ethernet Adapter
$wiredAdapter = Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.PhysicalMediaType -eq '802.3'}
```

This line is supposed to get the adapter properties of the Ethernet adapter (On both mine and the other individuals system there is only one)

On my system if I run the line and then output the results I get the following

```
PS C:\Users\Timothy> $wiredAdapter

Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
Ethernet                  Qualcomm Atheros AR8131 PCI-E Gigabi...       3 Up           xx-xx-xx-3B-22-78       100 Mbps
```

However when he tries copying the line directly he gets no output.

Can anyone suggest what's going wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you get on your the other persons computer if you run `(Get-Netadapter).PhysicalMediaType` and just the plain `Get-NetAdapter`?

Comment: I agree with @robert.westerlund The first step to solving this would be to examine the output without the `Where-Object` filter. This blog lists some possible values for `PhysicalMediaType`: http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/04/04/pstip-detecting-wi-fi-adapters/

Answer (score 0):

On my system Get-NetAdapter returns as I'd expect
The same as $ Wired above

```
PS C:\Users\Timothy> Get-NetAdapter

Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
WiFi 3                    Atheros AR5007UG Wireless Network Ad...      13 Disconnected 00-1D-0F-B1-82-B9          0 bps
Ethernet                  Qualcomm Atheros AR8131 PCI-E Gigabi...       3 Up           F4-6D-04-3B-22-78       100 Mbps
```

If I then do (Get-NetAdapter).PhysicalMediaType  I get the following

```
PS C:\Users\Timothy> (Get-NetAdapter).PhysicalMediaType
Native 802.11
802.3
```

I chose PhysicalMediaType as I was getting strange results off the media type for the Wireless Adapters.

```
PS C:\Users\Timothy> (Get-NetAdapter).MediaType
802.3
802.3
```

Still can't figure out why I get this result.

Thanks guys - the problem is that the other system returns different values for the Ethernet card.  What's annoying is that the card is the same model as mine

```
Native 802.11
Unspecified
Unspecified
Unspecified
Unspecified
Unspecified
Unspecified
```

I did come across the following page using the Get-WMIObject.

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Script-to-889c9505

However using that my wireless adapters were enumerated as wired adapters :(